# Using jquery write div html into PDF

Tags: jquery

```
var Pdfdoc = new jsPDF('p', '', 'a4', true);
Pdfdoc.fromHTML($("#modalDD").html(), 15,15, {
    'width': 170
});
Pdfdoc.save("Test.pdf");
```

This code create PDF and write content into it. But my problem is PDF (letter head ) in local folder and I wanna write content into that PDF. 
Please help

Comment: Confused, is the `C#` related or `jquery`, code looks like jquery but why the `C#` in titel

Comment: What you mean `local`? if your PDF is on your computer, than online JS can't access it.

Comment: Okkk then how can I do? Is any other way to do same using jquery